Why my program is crashing when executing loss.backward()?
I am trying to figure out why my program is crashing when executing loss.backward() but I think I am doing something wrong and I am running out of ideas now. Would you have any suggestion how to solve this issue?
Here is the code :
Trainer::Trainer(int64_t input_channels, int64_t num_actions, int64_t capacity) :     buffer(capacity),     
    network1(input_channels, num_actions),  
    target_network1(input_channels, num_actions),   
    dqn_optimizer(network1.parameters(), torch::optim::AdamOptions(0.001).betas({ 0.9, 0.999 })) {}  

torch::Tensor Trainer::compute_td_loss(int64_t batch_size, float gamma) {

    std::vector<std::tuple<torch::Tensor, torch::Tensor, torch::Tensor, torch::Tensor>> batch =
        buffer.sample_queue(batch_size);

    std::vector<torch::Tensor> states;
    std::vector<torch::Tensor> new_states;
    std::vector<torch::Tensor> actions;
    std::vector<torch::Tensor> rewards;

    for (auto i : batch) {
        states.push_back(std::get<0>(i).to(torch::kCPU));
        new_states.push_back(std::get<1>(i).to(torch::kCPU));
        actions.push_back(std::get<2>(i).to(torch::kCPU));
        rewards.push_back(std::get<3>(i).to(torch::kCPU));
    }

    torch::Tensor states_tensor;
    torch::Tensor new_states_tensor;
    torch::Tensor actions_tensor;
    torch::Tensor rewards_tensor;

    states_tensor = torch::cat(states, 0);
    new_states_tensor = torch::cat(new_states, 0);
    rewards_tensor = torch::cat(rewards, 0);
    actions_tensor = torch::cat(actions, 0);

    torch::Tensor q_values = network1.forward(states_tensor);
    torch::Tensor next_target_q_values = target_network1.forward(new_states_tensor);
    torch::Tensor next_q_values = network1.forward(new_states_tensor);
    actions_tensor = actions_tensor.to(torch::kInt64);

    for (int i = 0; i < batch_size; ++i) {
        // Extraire l'indice de l'action pour l'élément i
        int action_index = actions_tensor[i][0].item<int>();

        // Afficher action_index

        int j;

        if (action_index == 0) j = 0;
        else if (action_index == 12) j = 1;
        else if (action_index == 25) j = 2;
        else if (action_index == 50) j = 3;
        else if (action_index == 75) j = 4;
        else if (action_index == 88) j = 5;
        else j = 6;

        // Extraire la valeur Q correspondante de q_values pour l'indice d'action spécifié
        q_value[i] = q_values[i][j];
    }

    torch::Tensor maximum = std::get<1>(next_q_values.max(1));

    torch::Tensor next_q_value = torch::empty({ batch_size }, torch::kCPU);

    // Parcourir chaque élément du batch
    for (int i = 0; i < batch_size; ++i) {
        // Extraire l'indice de l'action pour l'élément i
        int action_index = maximum[i].item<int>();

        // Afficher action_index

        // Extraire la valeur Q correspondante de q_values pour l'indice d'action spécifié
        next_q_value[i] = next_target_q_values[i][action_index];
    }

    torch::Tensor expected_q_value = rewards_tensor.squeeze(1) + gamma * next_q_value;

    torch::Tensor loss = torch::mse_loss(q_value, expected_q_value);

    for (const auto& param : network1.parameters()) {
        if (!param.requires_grad()) {
            ::MessageBox(NULL, L"Paramètre n'a pas requires_grad défini sur true", L"compute_td_loss", MB_OK);
        }
    }

    dqn_optimizer.zero_grad();
    loss.backward();
    dqn_optimizer.step();

    return loss;
}

struct LinearModel : torch::nn::Module {
    torch::nn::Linear linear;

    LinearModel(int64_t input_size, int64_t output_size)
        : linear(register_module("linear", torch::nn::Linear(input_size, output_size))) {
    
        // Setting requires_grad=True for all parameters
        for (auto& param : linear->parameters()) {
            param.requires_grad_(true);
        }
    
    }

    torch::Tensor forward(torch::Tensor input) {

        torch::DeviceType device_type;
        device_type = torch::kCPU;
        torch::Device device(device_type);

        input = torch::relu(linear(input));

        return input;
    }

class Trainer {

private: ExperienceReplay buffer;
private: LinearModel network1, target_network1;
private: torch::optim::Adam dqn_optimizer;
private: double epsilon_start = 1.0;
private: double epsilon_final = 0.01;
private: int64_t epsilon_decay = 30000;
private: int64_t batch_size = 32;
private: float gamma = 0.99;

public:

    Trainer(int64_t input_channels, int64_t num_actions, int64_t capacity);

    torch::Tensor compute_td_loss(int64_t batch_size, float gamma);
    double epsilon_by_frame(int64_t frame_id);
    void loadstatedict(torch::nn::Module& model,
        torch::nn::Module& target_model);
    void Trainer::ddqn(struct_matrix* state, int indice, struct_matrix* nb_pos, struct_matrix* data, sortie* sortie0);
};

I tried to place all the tensors to kCPU ; I tried to detach the tensor next_q_value ; I check the dimensions of q_value and next_q_value ; they have the same dimension {32} and don't have NaN ; I check the loss value (=2.70521) ; I tried to add requires_grad = True to allow the loss to propagate
